# Where should I add a listener in react-native so that it listens for events in all screens?

Tags: firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

For example, I want to implement `react-native-netInfo` to determine whether the device has internet service or not, I understand I need to add a listener for this but adding it to each screen sounds exhausting. So, where should I add it to listen for it on each screen?

I also wish to implement CACHE.SIZE.LIMIT for Firebase Cloud Firestore, so where should I add that??

This is my project structure:

```
Project
|_App.js
|_index.js
|_app
  |_screens
  |_components
```

In my root/App.js or root/index.js ??

EDIT: Added App.js

```js
const AuthLoadingScreen = props => {
  function checkUser() {
    var user = auth().currentUser;

    props.navigation.navigate(user ? 'Main' : 'Auth');
  }
  checkUser();

  return (
    <View style={{flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center'}}>
      <Text>Loading...</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    LogIn: {
      screen: LogInScreen,
    },
    SignUp: {
      screen: SignUpScreen,
    },
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'LogIn',
  },
);

const MainStack = createStackNavigator(
  {
    Profile: {
      screen: ProfileScreen,
    },
    ReAuth: {
      screen: ReAuthScreen,
    },
    EditProfile: {
      screen: EditProfileScreen,
    },
    Home: {
      screen: HomeScreen,
    },
    CreateTask: {
      screen: CreateTaskScreen,
    },
    AllTasks: {
      screen: AllTasksScreen,
    },

  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'Home',
  },
);

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(
  createSwitchNavigator(
    {
      AuthLoad: AuthLoadingScreen,
      Auth: AuthStack,
      Main: MainStack,
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'AuthLoad',
    },
  ),
);

export default AppContainer;
```

Help will be much appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you should put it on App.js or wherever file that you place the navigator in it

Comment: I have edited the question and added my App.js, my App.js is not a component so can you tell where should I add the listeners??
Thank you.